# Filtering tags by mask

Tags: support, tag-watching

Is it possible to use mask on favorite or ignored tags? For example, I'm not interesting in any .Net technologies. But some questions has only version specific tags like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498796/entity-framework-image-gallery-in-mvc-5. It's annoying to exclude all manually.

Comment: You can use `intags:mine` in your search to get only posts with your favorite tags.

Comment: It's the same problem with version specific tags (like java-8 or oracle11g). Questions could be missed if I didn't add such tags.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is. If questions don't have the appropriate tags, how can you filter them?

Comment: The idea is using something like wildcards for tag filtering. "java-\*", "python\*"

Comment: You know you can already do that in search? `[python*]` gets expanded to every tag starting with `python`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! My shame, didn't try before ask question.